# Refining proof writing for Munkres Topology Exercises

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, proof-writing

I have been self studying Munkres Topology and am having difficulty determining the level of detail I should include in my proofs for chapter 16. I wish to show the following two conditions.

1. If $Y$ is a subspace of $X$, and $A$ is a subset of $Y$, then the topology $A$ inherits as a subspace of $Y$ is the same as the topology it inherits as a subspace of $X$.
2. If $\mathcal{T}$ and $\mathcal{T}'$ are toplogies on $X$ and $\mathcal{T}'$ is strictly finer than $\mathcal{T}$, $\mathcal{T}_Y'$ is finer than $\mathcal{T}_Y$ where $\mathcal{T}_Y'$ and $\mathcal{T}_Y$ denote the corresponding subspace topologies.

My attempted proof is as follows.

1: The subspace topology that $A$ inherits from $Y$ is given by

$$
\mathcal{T}_{AY} = \{A \cap U_Y : U_Y \in \mathcal{T}_Y\}
$$

and the subspace topology that $A$ inherits from $X$ is given by

$$
\mathcal{T}_{AX} = \{A \cap U_X : U_X \in \mathcal{T}_X\}
$$

where

$\mathcal{T}_X$ is the topology given on $X$ and

$$
\mathcal{T}_Y = \{Y \cap U_X : U_X \in \mathcal{T}_X \}
$$

Then
$$
\begin{align}
\mathcal{T}_{AY} &= \{A \cap U_Y : U_Y \in \{Y \cap U_X : U_X \in \mathcal{T}_X\}\} \\
&= \{A \cap Y \cap U_X : U_X \in \mathcal{T}_X \} \\
&= \{A \cap U_X : U_X \in \mathcal{T}_X\} \\
&= \mathcal{T}_{AX}
\end{align}
$$

as $A\subset Y$ implies $A \cap Y = A$.

2: Let $\mathcal{T}_Y$ and $\mathcal{T}_Y'$ be the subspace topolgies corresponding to $\mathcal{T}$ and $\mathcal{T}'$ respectively where $\mathcal{T} \subset \mathcal{T}'$.

$$
\begin{align}
U \in \mathcal{T}_Y = & \{U \cap Y : U \in \mathcal{T}\} \subset \\ 
& \{U \cap Y : U \in \mathcal{T}'\} = \mathcal{T}_Y'
\end{align}
$$

Question: Are my proofs correct? Have I included a sufficient amount of detail. With the second proof, I tacitly use the fact that $\mathcal{T} \subset \mathcal{T}'$ implies that $U \in \mathcal{T} \to U \in \mathcal{T}'$. I originally was curious if I would have to prove that two sets or topoligies are equal to one another by showing that if a element is a member of one than it is also a member of the other and vice versa. I feel that any additional details would just invent work for myself. Is this sentiment justified? Or, am I overconfident for a novice?

Comment: I don't see why $\tau'_Y$ should be *strictly* finer than $\tau_Y$. If e.g. $Y$ is a singleton then both topologies are the same.

Comment: Yes, you're correct. I wasn't being careful as I typed. I've corrected it now. Thank you. In fact, I only tried to prove that $\mathcal{T}_Y\subset \mathcal{T}_Y'$.

Comment: IMV both proofs are correct and complete.

Comment: I agree the proofs look generally fine. Especially if you're self studying, I would recommend looking up some example proofs from the same textbook or content (e.g. munkres solutions) to avoid this concern in the future... If you've convinced yourself adequately, you think your proof is good, and it roughly looks like proofs from others of similar statements, you're probably good :)

Comment: How much detail you put in a proof depends on your audience. In this case, your audience is yourself. I recommend writing for someone a month or two behind you in the material. That is, if the person you were a couple of months ago were given the definitions you've learned since, would find the argument convincing once they've had time to work through them, that is sufficient.